# Scrolling to the last position inside div element with overflow

Tags: html, reactjs, scroll, overflow, scrollto

I have an element with 4000px height and it's scrolling with overflow, I'm handling the last scroll position when page is left. When I back to this page I want it to be scrolled to the position I saved. The DOM structure looks like this

```
<div className="products"}>{childrens}</div>
```

So products have like 4000px height and let's imagine I have left page on 2300px height, with saved Y-axis param.
How do I scroll the element to this Y-axis on component mount with useEffect?
I tried `element.scrollTo(0, Y-axis);` but it's wasn't working
I'm assuming the problem is that I have the left side of the page fixed, and the right side is scrollable with overflow.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Ref to the parent container and get the height of the parent to move to Y-axis.

```
// Your parent container
<div ref={this.messageContainer}> your content   </div>


// To move to Y-axis
const height = this.messageContainer.scrollHeight;
this.messageContainer.scrollTo(0, height);
```